# How to make this line up correctly

Tags: html

I'm having a problem with this part of the code, for some reason the two elements contained in the two divs won't line up properly (side by side). I'm relatively new to this and would appreciate some help. It's probably a dumb mistake I've overlooked but I can't seem to get it right.

```
 <div style="background-image:url('http://royalelectric.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Yellow-Banner-1.jpg'); background-size:100%;">

 <div style="max-width:584px; min-width:205px; display:inline-block; width:48.8%; min-height:230px; display:inline-block; padding:1.2%;" align="left">
 <h1 align="left">Essentially Electric</h1>
 <h3 align="left">A Slightly Different Outlook on Our World!</h3>
 <a href="http://royalelectric.com/blog/why-isnt-there-a-standard-voltage-among-the-worlds-nations/"><img src="http://royalelectric.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/voltage-thumbnail.jpg" style="float:left"> 
 <h4 style="text-align:center; padding-left:4%; padding-right:4%;"> Why isn’t there a standard voltage among the world’s nations? </h4></a>
 <br>
 <p style="text-align:right; padding-left:5%; padding-right:5%;">
 If you’ve ever traveled overseas, you probably already know that there isn’t a worldwide standard for the voltage and frequency of alternating current (AC) electricity. Hopefully you didn’t find out the hard way. For various reasons...</p>
 <a href="http://royalelectric.com/blog/royal-blog/"><img src="http://royalelectric.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/button11.png" style="padding:4%;"></a>
 </div> 

 <div style="max-width:584px; min-width:205px; display:inline-block; width:48.5%; min-height:230px; display:inline-block; padding:1.2%;" align="left">
 <h1 align="left">Wow! Cool! Neat!</h1>
 <h3 align="left">Innovations + Great Ideas from our Manufacturers!</h3>
 <a href="http://royalelectric.com/blog/why-isnt-there-a-standard-voltage-among-the-worlds-nations/"><img src="http://royalelectric.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Klein-Tools-Switch-Drive-System-T1.jpg" align="left" style="padding-left:5%; padding-right:5%;"></a>
 <a href="http://royalelectric.com/blog/why-isnt-there-a-standard-voltage-among-the-worlds-nations/"><img src="http://royalelectric.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Klein-Tools-Switch-Drive-System-T1.jpg" align="right" style="padding-left:5%; padding-right:5%;"></a>
 </div> 
 </div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zawmd0uw/

Comment: I looked at the jsfiddle, but I can't tell how you want the elements to line up.  Which two elements should appear side by side?

Comment: You should consider using actual css instead of inline styling. It will make the html significantly easier to understand and allow you to detect redundancies like the fact that you have `display: inline-block` listed twice on one of your divs.

Comment: ok thanks! appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `float:right` to your 2nd div..

But Let me know you one thing.. This is really bad practice.

You can include bootstrap css to your site so that it will be responsive and this kinda styling can be avoided. For more info about bootstrap jus visit **[HERE](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/)**

Comment: thanks! working towards making my coding more effecient and it's becoming clear I've gotta move towards something like that. appreciate the help, and the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take the exact opposite answer to Kaushik! Remove 'display:inline-block;' from both DIVS (twice) and add Float:left to both.

```
<div style="background-image:url('http://royalelectric.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Yellow-Banner-1.jpg'); background-size:100%;">

 <div style="max-width:584px; min-width:205px; width:48.8%; min-height:230px;padding:1.2%;float:left;" align="left">
 <h1 align="left">Essentially Electric</h1>
 <h3 align="left">A Slightly Different Outlook on Our World!</h3>
 <a href="http://royalelectric.com/blog/why-isnt-there-a-standard-voltage-among-the-worlds-nations/"><img src="http://royalelectric.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/voltage-thumbnail.jpg" style="float:left"> 
 <h4 style="text-align:center; padding-left:4%; padding-right:4%;"> Why isn’t there a standard voltage among the world’s nations? </h4></a>
 <br>
 <p style="text-align:right; padding-left:5%; padding-right:5%;">
 If you’ve ever traveled overseas, you probably already know that there isn’t a worldwide standard for the voltage and frequency of alternating current (AC) electricity. Hopefully you didn’t find out the hard way. For various reasons...</p>
 <a href="http://royalelectric.com/blog/royal-blog/"><img src="http://royalelectric.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/button11.png" style="padding:4%;"></a>
 </div> 

 <div style="max-width:584px; min-width:205px; width:48.5%; min-height:230px; padding:1.2%;;float:left;" alig="left">
 <h1 align="left">Wow! Cool! Neat!</h1>
 <h3 align="left">Innovations + Great Ideas from our Manufacturers!</h3>
 <a href="http://royalelectric.com/blog/why-isnt-there-a-standard-voltage-among-the-worlds-nations/"><img src="http://royalelectric.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Klein-Tools-Switch-Drive-System-T1.jpg" align="left" style="padding-left:5%; padding-right:5%;"></a>
 <a href="http://royalelectric.com/blog/why-isnt-there-a-standard-voltage-among-the-worlds-nations/"><img src="http://royalelectric.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Klein-Tools-Switch-Drive-System-T1.jpg" align="right" style="padding-left:5%; padding-right:5%;"></a>
 </div> 
 </div>
```